# Why won't this work in PHP?

Tags: php, eval, constants

```
$constPrefix = '_CONST_';

if (strstr($content, $constPrefix)) {
    $constants = array('PHP_VERSION', '__FILE__');
    foreach($constants as $constant) {
        $constantOutput = eval($constant);
        $content = str_replace($constPrefix . $constant, $constantOutput, $content);
    }
}
```

Basically, just trying to parse some content and replace strings inside with the equivalent PHP constant. Is `eval()` what I should be using here? I've never actually found a reason to use it before, and it's almost 1am, and am wondering if that is a coincidence?

Comment: You should not `eval();`. Ever. (well, there are some exceptions, but they are few and far between)

Comment: What's the intent of the code? 

If it's 1am then I'd recommend getting some sleep and looking at it in the morning. Programming is much easier when your brain is well rested. Macho programming stints aren't productive.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can replace `eval` with [constant](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php):

```
$constantOutput = constant($constant);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just leave out the eval?

```
<?php
    $v = PHP_VERSION;
    $f = __FILE__;

    echo $v.' '.$f;
?>
```

gives

```
/tmp% php test.php 
5.2.10-2ubuntu6.4 /tmp/test.php
```

Comment: Just wanted to be more flexible. Though I know `eval` *is* a performance hit.